# Imagebutton slow changed to pressed state

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton, android-image, android-selector

I have a ImageButton and I've made a selector for it, so when I press the imagebutton, that another image shows up. But when pressing the imagebutton it seems like it has to wait 1 sec before changing the image. That isn't really good for user experience..

Is there a possibility to fix this? I've looked up some answers, but I don't now where to change this.

Here is my code

Selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/main_pressed" />
<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/main" />
</selector>
```

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/mainMosque"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:background="@null"
          android:contentDescription="@string/mainMosque"
          android:src="@drawable/main_btn_mosque" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you see this behavior on a real device or only on the emulator?

Comment: Is your image by any chance quite big? Maybe pressing the button requires GC run. Some logcat output would be useful. Also, you can run your app with the profiler and check yourself, what's taking so much time.

Comment: It is on a real device, Samsung Galaxy S3.

Image in xhdpi is 512x512 and the one in ldpi is 192x192.
How do I output this data with logcat and what is a profiler?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will solve the problem as it is really new problem to me. But you can try the followings

```
<ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/mainMosque"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:background="@drawable/main_btn_mosque"
      android:contentDescription="@string/mainMosque"/>
```

and the main_btn_mosque

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/main_pressed" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/main" />
</selector>
```

in the `selector` it is just an optimization as by default it is enabled.

Now if still the problem exists. Try one more thing. In place of `ImageButton` use `Button`.

Comment: I tried with your code and also tried it with a button, but no effect. Tried smaller images also no effect. I've read somewhere that it uses onpress (or on click don't remember) in stead of onTouch. You know something about that?

Comment: are you performing any costly operation in onClick

Comment: No, there isn't any logic yet, I only have been working with xml files. I'm also using fragments and viewpager to swipe horizontally but that won't be the issue

Comment: strange.. you can test some other things.. like removing image and see if the default selector works fine.. use another set of image .. and may be change image from code onClick

Comment: Tried it without background images and it still is slow. I'll try it on a emulator and I'll get back to you later.

Comment: If the problem is still there then recreate the whole project (this part only) and check..

Comment: I tried everything you told me but it really has a delay of 1 second. So if I press the button to start a new fragment/activty it seems like I never touched the button because it doesn't give me feedback that it's being touched.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ImageView instead of ImageButton, and use Glide library to load the images to the views which will increase the performance of the application, you have more info to read here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide
Hope this works for you!

Answer (score -1):

[How can I make a Button more responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040303/how-can-i-make-a-button-more-responsive)

This link provides some clue to as to what's causing this, however I haven't been successful in implementing the answer.

> Well... I usually extend Button class and override onTouchEvent method
>
> ```
> public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) 
> {
>    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
>    {
>       setPressed(true);
>    }
>    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
> }
> ```