# Slow button response in Android GridLayout

Tags: android, grid-layout

When I put my Buttons in a `GridLayout` the touch response is visually different than normally. On quick touch the change from default state to pressed state looks like normal, but when I touch and hold there is a very noticeable delay before the pressed button drawable is shown. Any idea of why?

I have tried to move the Button outside of the `GridLayout` and then it behaves like normal again - it changes to pressed state immediately. I have also tried `android:longClickable="false"` but that didn't solve the problem.

Here is my simple test:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/num_button"/> <!-- Same result without this drawable-->
</GridLayout>
```

My test device is a Google Nexus 10 running KitKat.

Comment: Could be related to the size of your drawables. How big are they ?

Comment: I just tried to remove my custom background, but the slow response was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I found a fix in a similar post here on SO.

You need to override a button and add the following code:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) 
{
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) setPressed(true);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Do you have a link to the other SO-post you mentioned?

Comment: Think I found it myself, here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040303/how-can-i-make-a-button-more-responsive