# Android ImageButton slow click response Inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, performance, scrollview, imagebutton, touch-event

I've always used buttons inside ScrollView but the ImageButton performs drastically slower if I use the following code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/custombtn"
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:src="@drawable/favorites"
                android:minHeight="90dip"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:minWidth="90dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I keep everything I have inside ScrollView and make the ImageButton onTouchEvent faster?

I presume the ScrollView is covering the whole layer and once I try to press the ImageButton it's actually interacting with ScrollView first and then ImageButton which is "behind" it. Is my assumption correct? How do I go about doing this properly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you setting `onTouchEvent` listener on image button?  If yes, why aren't you using `onClickListener`?

Comment: No I don't use any type of event. I just created this layout without any actual code and simply try out the buttons. The buttons respond very slowly when touched. If i remove the ScrollView, buttons respond faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why buttons within a [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) respond relatively slowly when pressed is because there is a slight delay to determine whether the touch is the start of a scroll/swipe event or the start of a long press event.

This delay is to avoid animating the button as pressed if the user is actually scrolling but happens to start the swipe on a button.

If you quickly tap a button within a [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html), however, you will see that the response is good.

To make the button more responsive, you can extend the Button class and override the onTouchEnd method as suggested in [How can I make a Button more responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8066633/4960725).

```
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        setPressed(true);
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```