# Slight lag using button setOnTouchListener

Tags: android, button, kotlin, ontouchlistener, lag

I am working on a project that requires the ***exact*** moment a button was touched to be recorded. For this, I am using `setOnTouchListener`.

I have simplified the listener down to a simple print statement. Within Logcat, there is a very slight delay between when the button is touched, and when "TOUCHED" gets printed.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mp: MediaPlayer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        tapButton.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                println("ACTION_DOWN")
                mp = MediaPlayer.create (this, R.raw.blip)
                mp.start()
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "ACTION_DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"))
                v.isPressed = true
            } else if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                println("ACTION_UP")
                background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
                v.isPressed = false
            }
            true
        }


    }
}
```

XML (as basic as it can get!)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="188dp"
            android:layout_height="288dp"
            android:id="@+id/tapButton" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**How can I prevent this lag, so that I can get the *precise* moment the button was touched?**

If it requires not using a button, and using a tappable view - that is fine too. It's imperative that this lag is removed. Additionally - if this lag is something that can't be addressed - perhaps I can offset the UI if I have the exact length (in milliseconds) that this lag occurs for. Open to ideas.

**EDIT:**

I believe I found the solution here; just don't know how to fix it.

[How can I make a Button more responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040303/how-can-i-make-a-button-more-responsive/5041276)

This thread states there's something called 'getTapTimeout' that intentionally puts a delay on a touch event to determine if it will be a tap or scroll. *THE CULPRIT?!*

**How do I set this to 0??**

Comment: Have you tried `clickListener` ?

Comment: @Varun Raj I have not. Can clickListener detect a touchDown event?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use logcat to tell.  Logcat sends data to a separate process.  It can be used for basic timings, but not for ms exact timings.

Every MotionEvent has a timestamp in it.  You can get it with motionEvent.getEventTime().  Use that for your timing data.

Comment: I have edited my question above. You will notice that along with printing a line on ACTION_DOWN, I am also changing the background color, presenting a Toast message, and playing a sound.  The background color reacts instantly (no delay). The print line, Toast & sound ALL reproduce the same exact lag/delay/offset.  Please see if you can recreate it on your end. I need all of this lag/delay/offset removed.

Comment: @Joe That's not going to happen.  Toast is again cross process communication, and its displayed at a time the Toast process decides to, which can be on any delay (if another toast is showing, it will wait until after it fades, for example).  Sound has a delay-  you need to set up DMA buffers, read data from disk, etc and its all being managed by an OS module that has to share access between every app running.  And having it synced up with a line printing to a log is just not going to happen.  You need to revisit your requirements and expectations.

Comment: getTapTimeout is causing a 100 ms delay on ACTION_DOWN to determine of a touch was a tap or a scroll. Check my question and look at the edit. I refuse to believe that this lag can not be removed. Piano or soundboard applications would cease to properly exist. If you're familar with iOS programming, i *simply* need to re-create a UIControlEventTouchDown button event. Which produces zero delay.

Answer (score -1):

You could create your own `CustomView` that extends `View` and overrides `dispatchTouchEvent`. You'll need to do something along the following lines,

```
interface CustomListener {
    fun customOnTouch()
}

class CustomTouchView : View {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

    private var customOnTouchListener:CustomListener? = null

    public fun setCustomOnTouchListener(listener: CustomListener) {
        this.customOnTouchListener = listener
    }

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        customOnTouchListener?.customOnTouch()
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

Comment: The difference between the two would be nanoseconds at best.  And it wouldn't fix the problem that he's using logcat to tell the time, which requires cross process communication

Comment: @GabeSechan I see, I assumed that the difference in time was caused due to the various other operations performed in `dispatchTouchEvent` before the listener is invoked. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @ChrisvinJem - Check my question. I edited it to include some important info. Looks like the culprit here is getTapTimeout, which is an intentional delay to determine if a touch event is a tap or scroll. I need to remove this delay!