# I need to remove TAP_TIMEOUT delay from onTouchEvent

Tags: android, button, kotlin, lag, motionevent

I am working on a project that requires precision when a button is touched. Meaning, the exact moment the button is touched, certain code in ACTION_DOWN must execute instantly.

I have discovered that there is actually an intended PREPRESSED state that delays the code for a specified interval. This interval is accessed in *MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN* by using `ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout()`. The purpose of this delay is to determine if the user is tapping or scrolling. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getTapTimeout()

**This lag needs to be removed.**

It's discussed more in this thread: [How can I make a Button more responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040303/how-can-i-make-a-button-more-responsive/5041276)

A few users suggested it can be removed by extending the Button class and override onTouchEvent.

I've attempted to extend a Button class, however, I don't know how to change this getTapTimeout to 0ms.

Here's my progress:

```
class NoLagButton : Button {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) isPressed = true
        println(ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout())
        ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout()
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

}
```

**By using the extended `NoLagButton`, how can I modify the length of getTapTimeout to 0?**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the value of `ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout()` without reflection hack. Do you have any problems with your solution?

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // code here will run instantly without delay
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event)
}
```

Comment: If it can't be removed, is there any way I can explicitly declare that the MotionEvent is a button? Perhaps that can disregard the timeout?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question. What do you want to do? If you want to execute some code immediately after the user touches the button then the solution with `NoLagButton` fits perfect for you.